# Android:Vertical and horizontal scrolling with constrains on top and left

Tags: java, android, user-interface, android-listview, android-scrollview

I would like to implement the following scroll view with vertical and horizontal scrolling:

```
       9:00    9:30    10:00    10:30    11:00    ...
item1  hi11    hi12    hi13     hi14     hi15     ...
item2  hi21    hi22    hi23     hi24     hi25     ...
item3  hi31    hi32    hi33     hi34     hi35     ...
...    ...     ...     ...      ...      ...      ...
```

but in addition I would like to apply the following two constrains:

1) If the user scrolls, from down to top, the area filled with "hi"; then the first row (time) must remain visible:

2) If the user scrolls, from right to left, the area filled with "hi"; then the first column (item1, item2, ...) must remain visible.

So, after scrolling vertical and horizontally the view can have the following appearance:

```
        16:00   16:30   17:00    17:30    18:00   ...
item23  abc     cde     efg      gfr      dfr     ...
item24  cvd     qwe     aqw      asw      dfr     ...
item25  dle     zwq     wer      ser      zzz     ...
...     ...     ...     ...      ...      ...     ...
```

The solution that I have found so far is based on Layouts and also creating items dynamically; however this solution has the problem of not synchronising the horizontal scrolling in the central area (hi11, hi12, hi13) with the time row (9:00 9:30 10:00 ...).

So, I need a way to detect horizontal scrolling in the "central area" and apply the same horizontal scroll to the "time area" (and, if possible, vice versa).

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/epg_time_list"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" />
                 <!-- In code: Create several TextView's time 
                  items and add them to this layout in order to
                  to create the first row which shows the time HH:mm -->

        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/epg_channel_list_master_master"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/epg_channel_list_master_detail"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/epg_channel_list_master"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <!-- In code: Create a TextView for every item
                      to create the first column (item1, item2, ...) -->

                </LinearLayout>

                <HorizontalScrollView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/epg_channel_list_detail_container"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="vertical" >


                            <!-- In code: Create a horizontal LinearLayout for
                            every row. Every row will contain several
                            TextViews with short names -->

                        </LinearLayout>
                </HorizontalScrollView>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution based on setting "onTouchListener" for every one of both horizontal scroll views; consequently I have added in the .xml two new identifiers (one for every horizontal scroll view), and in the code I have "setOnTouchListener" for every one of the aforementioned "horizontal scroll views to listen to each other; that is:

```
    mDetailHorizontalScrollView = (HorizontalScrollView) view
    .findViewById(R.id.detail_horizontal_scroll_view);
    mDetailHorizontalScrollView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
            int scrollX = view.getScrollX();
            int scrollY = view.getScrollY();

            mEpgTimeHorizontalScrollView.scrollTo(scrollX, scrollY);
                        return false;
            }

        });


    mEpgTimeHorizontalScrollView = (HorizontalScrollView) view
            .findViewById(R.id.epg_time_horizontal_scroll_view);
    mEpgTimeHorizontalScrollView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
            int scrollX = view.getScrollX();
            int scrollY = view.getScrollY();

            mDetailHorizontalScrollView.scrollTo(scrollX, scrollY);
                        return false;
            }

        });
```

And the identifiers for those horizontal scroll views are set up in the code according to the xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/epg_time_horizontal_scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/epg_time_list"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" />
                 <!-- In code: Create several TextView's time 
                  items and add them to this layout in order to
                  to create the first row which shows the time HH:mm -->
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/epg_channel_list_master_master"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/epg_channel_list_master_detail"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/epg_channel_list_master"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <!-- In code: Create a TextView for every item
                    to create the first column (item1, item2, ...) -->

                </LinearLayout>

                <HorizontalScrollView
                    android:id="@+id/detail_horizontal_scroll_view"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/epg_channel_list_detail_container"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="vertical" >


                        <!-- In code: Create a horizontal LinearLayout for
                        every row. Every row will contain several
                        TextViews with short names -->

                        </LinearLayout>
                </HorizontalScrollView>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```